# Blur effect is working properly in simulator but not in device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage, gpuimage

I'm working on a project where i'm implementing blur effect to images. This is the code i'm using..

```
GPUImageMotionBlurFilter *motionblurfilter=[[GPUImageMotionBlurFilter alloc]init];
        motionblurfilter.blurAngle=90.0;
        motionblurfilter.blurSize=15.0;
        UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        img.image=self.backgroundImgView.image;
        NSLog(@"00000 %@",img.image);
        // img.image=[motionblurfilter imageByFilteringImage:self.backgroundImgView.image];
        NSLog(@"11111 %@",img.image);
        // self.backgroundImgView.image=[motionblurfilter imageByFilteringImage:self.backgroundImgView.image];

        duplicateImgView.image = tattooImgView.image;

        UIImageView *img1=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        img1.image=self.tattooImgView.image;
        NSLog(@"00000 %@",img1.image);
        img1.image=[motionblurfilter imageByFilteringImage:self.tattooImgView.image];
        NSLog(@"11111 %@",img1.image);
        self.tattooImgView.image=[motionblurfilter imageByFilteringImage:self.tattooImgView.image];

        tattooImgView.alpha=0.70f;
        duplicateImgView.alpha=0.35f;
```

This code is working properly in simulater but not in device. please help me where i had gone wrong..

Comment: When you say it's not working properly on the device, what happens? A black image, an image with an incorrect application of the filter? What iOS version is the device? You need to give us a few more details here.

Comment: I have a similar effect when using this lib https://github.com/ArcticMinds/iOS-blur : works OK in the simulator but KO on the device (iPad 2) !

Answer (score 1):

This may answer your question:

[iOS 7 simulator vs device differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055509/ios-7-simulator-vs-device-differences)

extract:
"
The blur effect  will appear on:

- iPhone 4S and newer
- iPad 4th Generation and newer
- all iPad Mini
  "