# iOS 7 simulator vs device differences?

Tags: ios-simulator, uinavigationbar, ios7, xcode5, translucency

The base deployment of the app is iOS 7.0 and both device and the simulator are using 7.0.

The translucent effect on the simulator gives a blur to the content under `UINavigationBar`, but on the device, no blur. I've noticed a couple other difference tool. My `UIToolbar` was translucent on the simulator, but opaque on the device and there have been a few times where tints don't match.

For the nav bar though, why is it different and how do I get the blur effect? Without the blur, text under nav bar text could be distracting and confusing!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much digging, this is a hardware limitation. The blur effect is not enabled on the older devices due to GPU requirements/performance.

The blur effect will appear on:

- iPhone 4S and newer
- iPad 4th Generation and newer
- all iPad Mini

Comment: This is only half of the truth. I have the same effect inside a `UINavigationController` on an iPhone 5s.

Comment: This answer is not complete - I seem to have also reproduced a situation where UINavigationController bar is translucent on the simulator and non-translucent on an iPhone 5S. Working on it to find out why...

Comment: You guys find anything with this? I'm seeing blur on my sim and 5s, but not iPad 3rd gen.

Comment: *iPad 4th Generation and newer* - which means 3rd gen iPad will not have the blur effect